# How to fix type narrowing that doesn't work on nested object?

Tags: typescript

In the code snippets below, the second last line in `getChildEmail` show no error here as `child.email` is no longer `string|undefined` but `string` only because of [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#truthiness-narrowing).
However, type error is shown in last line of `getChildEmail`. This is unexpected as `child`'s type should now satisfy the type of `getEmail`'s argument.

```ts
type Parent = {
  name: string;
  email?: string;
  child: {
    name: string;
    email?: string;
  };
};

function getEmail({ name, email }: { name: string; email: string }) {
  return email;
}

function getChildEmail({ name, email, child }: Parent) {
  child.email.toLocaleLowerCase(); // error as expected, child.email is possibly undefined
  child.email && child.email.toLowerCase(); // working as expected, child.email is a string because of narrowing
  child.email && getEmail(child); // unexpected error as narrowing should make child satisfies the arguments of getEmail function
}
```

Why is it the case? What's the best practice to remove the last line type error?

You can also view it in the following [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.4#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJwgO2FAvFA3gKClZOAWwgC4oBnYBAS2QHMBuPKCIuGgGwH5yraGzfAGMAFlwAm5XPnyESfanSYt8bDj0UCV+AL7N9OHADMArsmHAaAe2RR6EYAFF2XABRYCxCABpWrzihdaS8FSiVBfw0tZSCASmwWJGBTBDt1LgMjMwsrW3tHAGFxTgkXDQ9Q3yiuPzFJIPJ4JFQEmSh60oA6DM4u4GsAGWthOE4IYYB3CARCuAoINzihDpKJHoCoADIt1ckNjX6h62nZ+cXllk713u3dh2cAt2vL3RwgA)

Comment: Relevant open github issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to cast the type of child to the correct type with a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions)

```
child.email && getEmail(child as Required<Parent['child']>);
```

Looks a bit cleaner if we define a Child type too

```
type Child = {
    name: string;
    email?: string;
}
type Parent = {
  name: string;
  email?: string;
  child: Child;
};

function getEmail({ name, email }: { name: string; email: string }) {
  return email;
}

function getChildEmail({ name, email, child }: Parent) {
  child.email?.toLocaleLowerCase();
  child.email && child.email.toLowerCase();
  child.email && getEmail(child as Required<Child>);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFgSwDYBMoF4oG8BQV9QB2AhgLYQBcUAzsAE4KEDmA3HgRKccgPxW0NmbAL45QkKAAVidCIWAZs7EuX71Grdp25I+NdUPYBjRKirxkKEWxwAzAK6EjwBAHtCUJhGABRLsgAKLCIyCAAaKG1kKGEqACUIAEd7BFkUAB4LVAA+AEolfFlgezoPKKQRHDtHZzcPL2AslD8dIJDyCPKIk0sYqmlZeXzcfB7UADpynnHgVwAZVyNiJAgFgHcIOhhiaggA3LZR0xRJ-yQoADILqDGT8pn51w2tnb2D42PTnUvrhpbA25QHZQBLJVIQDJNPKVIA)

Comment: Type assertion definitely works here, one solution that I found is `child as  { name: string; email: string }`. Do you know why TS is not smart enough to do it without type assertion? I like your asnwer because the use of `Required`.

Comment: you are giving up type safety like this, `getEmail( child as Required<Child>)` will accepts also undefined emails

Comment: No, by having `child.email &&` we have guaranteed that the child.email can no longer be undefined. That's the reason the second last line of `getChildEmail` has no type error.  It's just `TSC`  not smart enough for this.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is by adding a type guard (more about type guards, see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)). Try something like this:

```
function hasEmail(person: { name: string; email?: string }): person is {name: string; email: string} {
  return person.email !== undefined;
}
```

And then check it in this way:

```
hasEmail(child) && getEmail(child);
```

See the entire fixed code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.4&ssl=21&ssc=38&pln=21&pc=3#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJwgO2FAvFA3gKClZOAWwgC4oBnYBAS2QHMBuPKCIuGgGwH5yraGzfAGMAFlwAm5XPnyESfanSYt8bDj0UCV%20AL7N9OHADMArsmHAaAe2RR6EYAFF2XABRYCxCABpWrzihdaS8FSiVBfw0tZSCASmwWJGBTBDt1LgMjMwsrWyhROAoXDTdIBApbEPkycO1GKK5eOtjdOPJyyrsaCmwamMiMzgH6XUT8ZNS7TtsAOiGoAEJ0THMJCGM6CAksk3NLGzsHYABhcU4JEvdPGr8hvzFJIPJ4JFQEmShHi-mA2eBrAAZazCOCcCDAgDuEAQJyKEDccSEX3OEl%20GigADJMSjJOiuP8gdZobD4YjkYVigE3N8JAlsfZHFdODTUUicLocEA).

Comment: The non deprecated link is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)

Answer (score 0):

```
type Parent = {
  name: string;
  email?: string;
  child: {
    name: string;
    email?: string;
  };
};

function getEmail({ name, email }: any ) {
  return email;
}

function getChildEmail({ name, email, child }: Parent) {
  child?.email?.toLocaleLowerCase();
  child.email && child.email.toLowerCase();
  child.email && getEmail(child);
}
```

check your return type in getEmail() function. I think, it causes an error. As I understood, you only want to return email property, not child object

Comment: While your solution remove the type errors, the getEmail function is no longer typed now as it use `any` key word.

Comment: There is no error in getEmail, the colon is not a return signature, but for defining the types for the destructured props.